# Geopandas in Google Colab

Tags: geopandas

I am using Google Colab. I have installed the PyGMT. Now, I want to install the Geopandas but I got lots of errors when i type "!pip install geopandas" or "!conda install geopandas". Can you help me to install geopandas in googlecolab?
Here is my code;

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import os
import sys
import os
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
os.environ["GMT_LIBRARY_PATH"]="/usr/local/lib"
```

```py
!wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!chmod +x Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
!bash ./Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -bfp /usr/local
!conda update conda -y -q
!conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
!conda install -q -y --prefix /usr/local python=3.8 pygmt

import sys
import os
sys.path.append('/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
os.environ["GMT_LIBRARY_PATH"]="/usr/local/lib"
```

```py
!pip install geopandas
```

```py
import pygmt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
```

[image: My Code]

When I do !pip install geopandas and import it, it says that: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyproj._network'

[image: Error]

Answer (score 7):

have you tried using

```
!pip install --upgrade geopandas
```

don't forget to also update the other dependencies

```
!pip install --upgrade pyshp

!pip install --upgrade shapely

!pip install --upgrade descartes
```

Found it in this Google Colab tutorial, https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1We-LMiSeucESsiB1tmvL9nZrntyWsri-#scrollTo=xIXl9KBOxVKE

Hope it works,

Comment: As a one-liner: `!pip install --upgrade geopandas pyshp shapely descartes`

Comment: Note that [`descartes` is no longer required](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/changelog.html#version-0-9-0-february-28-2021)

Answer (score 5):

Conda is not available in google colab by default like numpy, pandas etc is. So doing `!conda install geopandas` won't do any help. There's another way around it though. You CAN install conda on google colab and using it you can install other packages. Here's how:

```
!pip install -q condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install()
```

Then try installing with `!conda install geopandas` and import it using `import geopandas`

Answer (score 2):

You can use these three lines to import geopandas in colab:

```
!apt install libspatialindex-dev
!pip install rtree
!pip install geopandas
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).